# Django: ModelForm not binding to request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I have the following model:

```
class Tracking(models.Model):

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    week = models.IntegerField(choices=settings.WEEK_CHOICES, blank=True)
    term = models.IntegerField(choices=settings.TERM_CHOICES, blank=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=settings.YEAR_CHOICES, blank=True)
    target = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    monday = models.IntegerField()
    tuesday = models.IntegerField()
    wednesday = models.IntegerField()
    thursday = models.IntegerField()
    friday = models.IntegerField()
```

which is linked to this form:

```
class AddTrackingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        super(AddTrackingForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:

        model = models.Tracking
        fields = '__all__'
```

Once a user fills out the form, I want to save the instance to the database:

```
class TrackingView(generic.TemplateView):

    template_name = "tracking.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = forms.AddTrackingForm()
        form.fields['person'].queryset = models.Person.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-last_name', '-first_name')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = forms.AddTrackingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.person = models.Person.objects.get(id=int(request.POST['person']))

            model_instance.save()
        return redirect('/tracking')
```

However, the `form.is_valid()` never returns True. Printing out the errors gives me blank for `form.errors` and: `<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <AddTrackingForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(person;week;term;year;b1;b2;monday;tuesday;wednesday;thursday;friday)>>` for `form.non_field_errors`.

No matter what I try, I can't get the instance to bind. I thought it might be that the post data is received as strings and not being valid data for the `model.IntegerField()`'s, so I might need to override `form.clean()` and cast all relevant fields to ints. However, that didn't work. What else could cause my form not to bind to an instance?

**Update**
Here is my template. the form is in a table, and I make an Ajax query to make sure the data hasn't already been entered before submitting the form:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>                        
    <form id="tracking_form" method="POST" action="/tracking">                      
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <td>{{ field }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitIfUnique()" value="Add Points"></td>
    </form>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
<script>
        var form_data = {
            'person': $('#id_person').val(),
            'year': $('#id_year').val(),
            'term': $('#id_term').val(),
            'week': $('#id_week').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/tracking/is_unique", 
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response){
                var form = $('#tracking_form');
                var submit = true;
                if(!response['is_unique']){
                    confirm = confirm("This data has already been entered for " + response['person'] + ". Are you sure you want to overwrite this?");
                    if(!confirm){ submit = false; }
                }
                if(submit){ form.submit(); }
            }
        });

</script>
```

I know the form is submitting correctly, since I can print out the all the data from the request in `TrackingView.post()`. For the sake of completeness, here is the form once the template is rendered in the browser:

```
<form id="tracking_form" method="POST" action="/tracking">                      
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='EZ...Uc' />
<td><select name="person" required id="id_person">
    <option value="18" selected>Test Person 1</option>
    <option value="19">Test Person 2</option>
</select></td>      
<td><select name="week" required id="id_week">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select></td>                  
<td><select name="term" required id="id_term">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select></td>      
<td><select name="year" required id="id_year">
     <option value="2017">2017</option>
     <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" name="target" required id="id_target" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="monday" min="0" max="100" required id="id_monday" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="tuesday"  min="0" max="100" required id="id_tuesday" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="wednesday"  min="0" max="100" required id="id_wednesday" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="thursday" min="0" max="100" required id="id_thursday" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="friday" min="0" max="100" required id="id_friday" /></td>
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitIfUnique()" value="Add Points"></td>
```

Comment: can you post the template html one too ?

Comment: @A.Raouf I've updated my question with the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the output you're getting. The form *is* bound, otherwise `form.errors` wouldn't work. But `non_field_errors` is a *method*, which you need to call: `form.non_field_errors()` .

The main issue is that you always redirect after post, even if the form is not valid. You should only do that when it *is* valid; otherwise, you should redisplay the template with the invalid form. Also, you should display `{{ form.errors }}` in that template.

Note also you are using the wrong view base class; a CreateView will do everything your code does, including redisplay the form on error. Generally if you find yourself overriding `get` and `post` on a class based view you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I took so long to mark this as correct. It works perfectly.